# LLVM 3.4 linker errors on VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker, llvm

I have built the LLVM 3.4 from source using Cmake. I referred to documentation for Getting Started with the LLVM System using Microsoft Visual Studio for the installation.

I now want to use the LLVM in my own project. I have added the LLVM libraries in VS 2012 using the `Properties -> C/C++ -> General`. When I try to build my compiler, I get the following linker errors when I Build my project:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LLVMInitializeX86TargetInfo referenced in function "bool __cdecl llvm::InitializeNativeTarget(void)" (?InitializeNativeTarget@llvm@@YA_NXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LLVMInitializeX86Target referenced in function "bool __cdecl llvm::InitializeNativeTarget(void)" (?InitializeNativeTarget@llvm@@YA_NXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LLVMInitializeX86TargetMC referenced in function "bool __cdecl llvm::InitializeNativeTarget(void)" (?InitializeNativeTarget@llvm@@YA_NXZ)
```

I am new to LLVM, any help would be appreciated. I have gone through the solutions @[Failed to link obj files generated by LLVM compiler using MS Linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080561/failed-to-link-obj-files-generated-by-llvm-compiler-using-ms-linker) and also @ [Clang, Microsoft linker and standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452967/clang-microsoft-linker-and-standard-library) but they did not improve my situation.

Some information about my system:

- Windows 8 (x64 arch)
- no Cygwin installed
- latest winflexbison in use

A more detailed error list from my failed build in VS 2012:

```
    Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl llvm::Value::printCustom(class llvm::raw_ostream &)const " (?printCustom@Value@llvm@@MEBAXAEAVraw_ostream@2@@Z)  E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl llvm::Value::printCustom(class llvm::raw_ostream &)const " (?printCustom@Value@llvm@@MEBAXAEAVraw_ostream@2@@Z)  E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl llvm::Value::setName(class llvm::Twine const &)" (?setName@Value@llvm@@QEAAXAEBVTwine@2@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class llvm::Value * __cdecl NFunctionDeclaration::codeGen(class CodeGenContext &)" (?codeGen@NFunctionDeclaration@@UEAAPEAVValue@llvm@@AEAVCodeGenContext@@@Z)  E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl llvm::Value::setName(class llvm::Twine const &)" (?setName@Value@llvm@@QEAAXAEBVTwine@2@@Z) E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl llvm::llvm_unreachable_internal(char const *,char const *,unsigned int)" (?llvm_unreachable_internal@llvm@@YAXPEBD0I@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl llvm::User::operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3User@llvm@@SAXPEAXI@Z)    E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   8   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl llvm::llvm_unreachable_internal(char const *,char const *,unsigned int)" (?llvm_unreachable_internal@llvm@@YAXPEBD0I@Z) E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   9   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __cdecl llvm::User::anchor(void)" (?anchor@User@llvm@@EEAAXXZ) E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   10  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __cdecl llvm::User::anchor(void)" (?anchor@User@llvm@@EEAAXXZ) E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   11  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: static void * __cdecl llvm::User::operator new(unsigned __int64,unsigned int)" (??2User@llvm@@KAPEAX_KI@Z) referenced in function "public: static void * __cdecl llvm::StoreInst::operator new(unsigned __int64)" (??2StoreInst@llvm@@SAPEAX_K@Z) E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   12  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: static void * __cdecl llvm::User::operator new(unsigned __int64,unsigned int)" (??2User@llvm@@KAPEAX_KI@Z)    E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   13  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl llvm::User::operator delete(void *)" (??3User@llvm@@SAXPEAX@Z) referenced in function "int `public: virtual class llvm::Value * __cdecl NIdentifier::codeGen(class CodeGenContext &)'::`1'::dtor$2" (?dtor$2@?0??codeGen@NIdentifier@@UEAAPEAVValue@llvm@@AEAVCodeGenContext@@@Z@4HA)    E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   14  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl llvm::User::operator delete(void *)" (??3User@llvm@@SAXPEAX@Z)   E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   15  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl llvm::Instruction::~Instruction(void)" (??1Instruction@llvm@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "int `private: __cdecl llvm::CallInst::CallInst(class CallInst::Value *,class CallInst::ArrayRef<class llvm::Value *>,class CallInst::Twine const &,class CallInst::BasicBlock *)'::`1'::dtor$0" (?dtor$0@?0???0CallInst@llvm@@AEAA@PEAVValue@1@V?$ArrayRef@PEAVValue@llvm@@@1@AEBVTwine@1@PEAVBasicBlock@1@@Z@4HA) E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   16  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl llvm::Instruction::~Instruction(void)" (??1Instruction@llvm@@UEAA@XZ)    E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   17  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: __cdecl llvm::Instruction::Instruction(class llvm::Type *,unsigned int,class llvm::Use *,unsigned int,class llvm::BasicBlock *)" (??0Instruction@llvm@@IEAA@PEAVType@1@IPEAVUse@1@IPEAVBasicBlock@1@@Z) referenced in function "private: __cdecl llvm::CallInst::CallInst(class llvm::Value *,class llvm::ArrayRef<class llvm::Value *>,class llvm::Twine const &,class llvm::BasicBlock *)" (??0CallInst@llvm@@AEAA@PEAVValue@1@V?$ArrayRef@PEAVValue@llvm@@@1@AEBVTwine@1@PEAVBasicBlock@1@@Z)  E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   18  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: __cdecl llvm::Instruction::Instruction(class llvm::Type *,unsigned int,class llvm::Use *,unsigned int,class llvm::BasicBlock *)" (??0Instruction@llvm@@IEAA@PEAVType@1@IPEAVUse@1@IPEAVBasicBlock@1@@Z)   E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   19  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: __cdecl llvm::BasicBlock::BasicBlock(class llvm::LLVMContext &,class llvm::Twine const &,class llvm::Function *,class llvm::BasicBlock *)" (??0BasicBlock@llvm@@AEAA@AEAVLLVMContext@1@AEBVTwine@1@PEAVFunction@1@PEAV01@@Z) referenced in function "public: static class llvm::BasicBlock * __cdecl llvm::BasicBlock::Create(class llvm::LLVMContext &,class llvm::Twine const &,class llvm::Function *,class llvm::BasicBlock *)" (?Create@BasicBlock@llvm@@SAPEAV12@AEAVLLVMContext@2@AEBVTwine@2@PEAVFunction@2@PEAV12@@Z)  E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   20  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: __cdecl llvm::BasicBlock::BasicBlock(class llvm::LLVMContext &,class llvm::Twine const &,class llvm::Function *,class llvm::BasicBlock *)" (??0BasicBlock@llvm@@AEAA@AEAVLLVMContext@1@AEBVTwine@1@PEAVFunction@1@PEAV01@@Z)    E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   21  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl llvm::APInt::initSlowCase(class llvm::APInt const &)" (?initSlowCase@APInt@llvm@@AEAAXAEBV12@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl llvm::APInt::APInt(class llvm::APInt const &)" (??0APInt@llvm@@QEAA@AEBV01@@Z)    E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   22  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class llvm::Type * __cdecl llvm::Type::getVoidTy(class llvm::LLVMContext &)" (?getVoidTy@Type@llvm@@SAPEAV12@AEAVLLVMContext@2@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl CodeGenContext::generateCode(class NBlock &)" (?generateCode@CodeGenContext@@QEAAXAEAVNBlock@@@Z) E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   23  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class llvm::Type * __cdecl llvm::Type::getVoidTy(class llvm::LLVMContext &)" (?getVoidTy@Type@llvm@@SAPEAV12@AEAVLLVMContext@2@@Z)    E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   24  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class llvm::Type * __cdecl llvm::Type::getDoubleTy(class llvm::LLVMContext &)" (?getDoubleTy@Type@llvm@@SAPEAV12@AEAVLLVMContext@2@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class llvm::Value * __cdecl NDouble::codeGen(class CodeGenContext &)" (?codeGen@NDouble@@UEAAPEAVValue@llvm@@AEAVCodeGenContext@@@Z)   E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   25  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class llvm::IntegerType * __cdecl llvm::Type::getInt64Ty(class llvm::LLVMContext &)" (?getInt64Ty@Type@llvm@@SAPEAVIntegerType@2@AEAVLLVMContext@2@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class llvm::Value * __cdecl NInteger::codeGen(class CodeGenContext &)" (?codeGen@NInteger@@UEAAPEAVValue@llvm@@AEAVCodeGenContext@@@Z) E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   26  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class llvm::IntegerType * __cdecl llvm::Type::getInt64Ty(class llvm::LLVMContext &)" (?getInt64Ty@Type@llvm@@SAPEAVIntegerType@2@AEAVLLVMContext@2@@Z)    E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   27  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class llvm::FunctionType * __cdecl llvm::FunctionType::get(class llvm::Type *,class llvm::ArrayRef<class llvm::Type *>,bool)" (?get@FunctionType@llvm@@SAPEAV12@PEAVType@2@V?$ArrayRef@PEAVType@llvm@@@2@_N@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class llvm::Value * __cdecl NFunctionDeclaration::codeGen(class CodeGenContext &)" (?codeGen@NFunctionDeclaration@@UEAAPEAVValue@llvm@@AEAVCodeGenContext@@@Z) E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   28  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class llvm::FunctionType * __cdecl llvm::FunctionType::get(class llvm::Type *,class llvm::ArrayRef<class llvm::Type *>,bool)" (?get@FunctionType@llvm@@SAPEAV12@PEAVType@2@V?$ArrayRef@PEAVType@llvm@@@2@_N@Z)    E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   29  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl llvm::Function::BuildLazyArguments(void)const " (?BuildLazyArguments@Function@llvm@@AEBAXXZ) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl llvm::Function::CheckLazyArguments(void)const " (?CheckLazyArguments@Function@llvm@@AEBAXXZ)    E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   30  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl llvm::Function::BuildLazyArguments(void)const " (?BuildLazyArguments@Function@llvm@@AEBAXXZ)   E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   31  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: __cdecl llvm::Function::Function(class llvm::FunctionType *,enum llvm::GlobalValue::LinkageTypes,class llvm::Twine const &,class llvm::Module *)" (??0Function@llvm@@AEAA@PEAVFunctionType@1@W4LinkageTypes@GlobalValue@1@AEBVTwine@1@PEAVModule@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: static class llvm::Function * __cdecl llvm::Function::Create(class llvm::FunctionType *,enum llvm::GlobalValue::LinkageTypes,class llvm::Twine const &,class llvm::Module *)" (?Create@Function@llvm@@SAPEAV12@PEAVFunctionType@2@W4LinkageTypes@GlobalValue@2@AEBVTwine@2@PEAVModule@2@@Z)  E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   32  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: __cdecl llvm::Function::Function(class llvm::FunctionType *,enum llvm::GlobalValue::LinkageTypes,class llvm::Twine const &,class llvm::Module *)" (??0Function@llvm@@AEAA@PEAVFunctionType@1@W4LinkageTypes@GlobalValue@1@AEBVTwine@1@PEAVModule@1@@Z)  E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   33  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class llvm::Function * __cdecl llvm::Module::getFunction(class llvm::StringRef)const " (?getFunction@Module@llvm@@QEBAPEAVFunction@2@VStringRef@2@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class llvm::Value * __cdecl NMethodCall::codeGen(class CodeGenContext &)" (?codeGen@NMethodCall@@UEAAPEAVValue@llvm@@AEAVCodeGenContext@@@Z)   E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   34  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class llvm::LLVMContext & __cdecl llvm::getGlobalContext(void)" (?getGlobalContext@llvm@@YAAEAVLLVMContext@1@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual class llvm::Value * __cdecl NInteger::codeGen(class CodeGenContext &)" (?codeGen@NInteger@@UEAAPEAVValue@llvm@@AEAVCodeGenContext@@@Z)  E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   35  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class llvm::LLVMContext & __cdecl llvm::getGlobalContext(void)" (?getGlobalContext@llvm@@YAAEAVLLVMContext@1@XZ) E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   36  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class llvm::LLVMContext & __cdecl llvm::getGlobalContext(void)" (?getGlobalContext@llvm@@YAAEAVLLVMContext@1@XZ) E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\main.obj
Error   37  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl llvm::legacy::PassManager::PassManager(void)" (??0PassManager@legacy@llvm@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl CodeGenContext::generateCode(class NBlock &)" (?generateCode@CodeGenContext@@QEAAXAEAVNBlock@@@Z)   E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   38  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl llvm::legacy::PassManager::~PassManager(void)" (??1PassManager@legacy@llvm@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl CodeGenContext::generateCode(class NBlock &)" (?generateCode@CodeGenContext@@QEAAXAEAVNBlock@@@Z)  E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   39  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl llvm::legacy::PassManager::add(class llvm::Pass *)" (?add@PassManager@legacy@llvm@@UEAAXPEAVPass@3@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl CodeGenContext::generateCode(class NBlock &)" (?generateCode@CodeGenContext@@QEAAXAEAVNBlock@@@Z)   E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   40  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __cdecl llvm::legacy::PassManager::run(class llvm::Module &)" (?run@PassManager@legacy@llvm@@QEAA_NAEAVModule@3@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl CodeGenContext::generateCode(class NBlock &)" (?generateCode@CodeGenContext@@QEAAXAEAVNBlock@@@Z)  E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   41  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class llvm::BinaryOperator * __cdecl llvm::BinaryOperator::Create(enum llvm::Instruction::BinaryOps,class llvm::Value *,class llvm::Value *,class llvm::Twine const &,class llvm::BasicBlock *)" (?Create@BinaryOperator@llvm@@SAPEAV12@W4BinaryOps@Instruction@2@PEAVValue@2@1AEBVTwine@2@PEAVBasicBlock@2@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class llvm::Value * __cdecl NBinaryOperator::codeGen(class CodeGenContext &)" (?codeGen@NBinaryOperator@@UEAAPEAVValue@llvm@@AEAVCodeGenContext@@@Z)  E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   42  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl llvm::AllocaInst::AllocaInst(class llvm::Type *,class llvm::Twine const &,class llvm::BasicBlock *)" (??0AllocaInst@llvm@@QEAA@PEAVType@1@AEBVTwine@1@PEAVBasicBlock@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class llvm::Value * __cdecl NVariableDeclaration::codeGen(class CodeGenContext &)" (?codeGen@NVariableDeclaration@@UEAAPEAVValue@llvm@@AEAVCodeGenContext@@@Z)    E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   43  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl llvm::LoadInst::LoadInst(class llvm::Value *,char const *,bool,class llvm::BasicBlock *)" (??0LoadInst@llvm@@QEAA@PEAVValue@1@PEBD_NPEAVBasicBlock@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class llvm::Value * __cdecl NIdentifier::codeGen(class CodeGenContext &)" (?codeGen@NIdentifier@@UEAAPEAVValue@llvm@@AEAVCodeGenContext@@@Z)    E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   44  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl llvm::StoreInst::StoreInst(class llvm::Value *,class llvm::Value *,bool,class llvm::BasicBlock *)" (??0StoreInst@llvm@@QEAA@PEAVValue@1@0_NPEAVBasicBlock@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class llvm::Value * __cdecl NAssignment::codeGen(class CodeGenContext &)" (?codeGen@NAssignment@@UEAAPEAVValue@llvm@@AEAVCodeGenContext@@@Z) E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   45  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl llvm::CallInst::init(class llvm::Value *,class llvm::ArrayRef<class llvm::Value *>,class llvm::Twine const &)" (?init@CallInst@llvm@@AEAAXPEAVValue@2@V?$ArrayRef@PEAVValue@llvm@@@2@AEBVTwine@2@@Z) referenced in function "private: __cdecl llvm::CallInst::CallInst(class llvm::Value *,class llvm::ArrayRef<class llvm::Value *>,class llvm::Twine const &,class llvm::BasicBlock *)" (??0CallInst@llvm@@AEAA@PEAVValue@1@V?$ArrayRef@PEAVValue@llvm@@@1@AEBVTwine@1@PEAVBasicBlock@1@@Z)  E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   46  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl llvm::CallInst::init(class llvm::Value *,class llvm::ArrayRef<class llvm::Value *>,class llvm::Twine const &)" (?init@CallInst@llvm@@AEAAXPEAVValue@2@V?$ArrayRef@PEAVValue@llvm@@@2@AEBVTwine@2@@Z)   E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   47  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class llvm::CallInst * __cdecl llvm::CallInst::clone_impl(void)const " (?clone_impl@CallInst@llvm@@MEBAPEAV12@XZ) E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   48  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class llvm::CallInst * __cdecl llvm::CallInst::clone_impl(void)const " (?clone_impl@CallInst@llvm@@MEBAPEAV12@XZ) E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   49  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl llvm::CallInst::~CallInst(void)" (??1CallInst@llvm@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __cdecl llvm::CallInst::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GCallInst@llvm@@UEAAPEAXI@Z) E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   50  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl llvm::CallInst::~CallInst(void)" (??1CallInst@llvm@@UEAA@XZ) E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   51  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: __cdecl llvm::ReturnInst::ReturnInst(class llvm::LLVMContext &,class llvm::Value *,class llvm::BasicBlock *)" (??0ReturnInst@llvm@@AEAA@AEAVLLVMContext@1@PEAVValue@1@PEAVBasicBlock@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: static class llvm::ReturnInst * __cdecl llvm::ReturnInst::Create(class llvm::LLVMContext &,class llvm::Value *,class llvm::BasicBlock *)" (?Create@ReturnInst@llvm@@SAPEAV12@AEAVLLVMContext@2@PEAVValue@2@PEAVBasicBlock@2@@Z)  E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   52  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: __cdecl llvm::ReturnInst::ReturnInst(class llvm::LLVMContext &,class llvm::BasicBlock *)" (??0ReturnInst@llvm@@AEAA@AEAVLLVMContext@1@PEAVBasicBlock@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: static class llvm::ReturnInst * __cdecl llvm::ReturnInst::Create(class llvm::LLVMContext &,class llvm::BasicBlock *)" (?Create@ReturnInst@llvm@@SAPEAV12@AEAVLLVMContext@2@PEAVBasicBlock@2@@Z)  E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   53  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: __cdecl llvm::ReturnInst::ReturnInst(class llvm::LLVMContext &,class llvm::BasicBlock *)" (??0ReturnInst@llvm@@AEAA@AEAVLLVMContext@1@PEAVBasicBlock@1@@Z)  E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   54  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class llvm::ModulePass * __cdecl llvm::createPrintModulePass(class llvm::raw_ostream *,bool,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?createPrintModulePass@llvm@@YAPEAVModulePass@1@PEAVraw_ostream@1@_NAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl CodeGenContext::generateCode(class NBlock &)" (?generateCode@CodeGenContext@@QEAAXAEAVNBlock@@@Z)   E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   55  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LLVMLinkInJIT referenced in function "public: __cdecl `anonymous namespace'::ForceJITLinking::ForceJITLinking(void)" (??0ForceJITLinking@?A0x58e120ca@@QEAA@XZ)   E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   56  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol LLVMLinkInJIT E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   57  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol LLVMLinkInJIT E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\main.obj
Error   58  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class llvm::TargetMachine * __cdecl llvm::EngineBuilder::selectTarget(void)" (?selectTarget@EngineBuilder@llvm@@QEAAPEAVTargetMachine@2@XZ) referenced in function "public: class llvm::ExecutionEngine * __cdecl llvm::EngineBuilder::create(void)" (?create@EngineBuilder@llvm@@QEAAPEAVExecutionEngine@2@XZ)  E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   59  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class llvm::ExecutionEngine * __cdecl llvm::EngineBuilder::create(class llvm::TargetMachine *)" (?create@EngineBuilder@llvm@@QEAAPEAVExecutionEngine@2@PEAVTargetMachine@2@@Z) referenced in function "public: class llvm::ExecutionEngine * __cdecl llvm::EngineBuilder::create(void)" (?create@EngineBuilder@llvm@@QEAAPEAVExecutionEngine@2@XZ)   E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   60  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class llvm::raw_ostream & __cdecl llvm::outs(void)" (?outs@llvm@@YAAEAVraw_ostream@1@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl CodeGenContext::generateCode(class NBlock &)" (?generateCode@CodeGenContext@@QEAAXAEAVNBlock@@@Z)  E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   61  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class llvm::ConstantInt * __cdecl llvm::ConstantInt::get(class llvm::IntegerType *,unsigned __int64,bool)" (?get@ConstantInt@llvm@@SAPEAV12@PEAVIntegerType@2@_K_N@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class llvm::Value * __cdecl NInteger::codeGen(class CodeGenContext &)" (?codeGen@NInteger@@UEAAPEAVValue@llvm@@AEAVCodeGenContext@@@Z)  E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   62  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class llvm::Constant * __cdecl llvm::ConstantFP::get(class llvm::Type *,double)" (?get@ConstantFP@llvm@@SAPEAVConstant@2@PEAVType@2@N@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class llvm::Value * __cdecl NDouble::codeGen(class CodeGenContext &)" (?codeGen@NDouble@@UEAAPEAVValue@llvm@@AEAVCodeGenContext@@@Z) E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\codegen.obj
Error   63  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class llvm::Constant * __cdecl llvm::Constant::getNullValue(class llvm::Type *)" (?getNullValue@Constant@llvm@@SAPEAV12@PEAVType@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl createEchoFunction(class CodeGenContext &,class llvm::Function *)" (?createEchoFunction@@YAXAEAVCodeGenContext@@PEAVFunction@llvm@@@Z)    E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   64  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class llvm::IntegerType * __cdecl llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(class llvm::LLVMContext &)" (?getInt32Ty@Type@llvm@@SAPEAVIntegerType@2@AEAVLLVMContext@2@@Z) referenced in function "class llvm::Function * __cdecl createPrintfFunction(class CodeGenContext &)" (?createPrintfFunction@@YAPEAVFunction@llvm@@AEAVCodeGenContext@@@Z)  E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   65  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class llvm::PointerType * __cdecl llvm::Type::getInt8PtrTy(class llvm::LLVMContext &,unsigned int)" (?getInt8PtrTy@Type@llvm@@SAPEAVPointerType@2@AEAVLLVMContext@2@I@Z) referenced in function "class llvm::Function * __cdecl createPrintfFunction(class CodeGenContext &)" (?createPrintfFunction@@YAPEAVFunction@llvm@@AEAVCodeGenContext@@@Z)    E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   66  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class llvm::IntegerType * __cdecl llvm::IntegerType::get(class llvm::LLVMContext &,unsigned int)" (?get@IntegerType@llvm@@SAPEAV12@AEAVLLVMContext@2@I@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl createEchoFunction(class CodeGenContext &,class llvm::Function *)" (?createEchoFunction@@YAXAEAVCodeGenContext@@PEAVFunction@llvm@@@Z) E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   67  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class llvm::ArrayType * __cdecl llvm::ArrayType::get(class llvm::Type *,unsigned __int64)" (?get@ArrayType@llvm@@SAPEAV12@PEAVType@2@_K@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl createEchoFunction(class CodeGenContext &,class llvm::Function *)" (?createEchoFunction@@YAXAEAVCodeGenContext@@PEAVFunction@llvm@@@Z)    E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   68  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl llvm::GlobalVariable::GlobalVariable(class llvm::Module &,class llvm::Type *,bool,enum llvm::GlobalValue::LinkageTypes,class llvm::Constant *,class llvm::Twine const &,class llvm::GlobalVariable *,enum llvm::GlobalVariable::ThreadLocalMode,unsigned int,bool)" (??0GlobalVariable@llvm@@QEAA@AEAVModule@1@PEAVType@1@_NW4LinkageTypes@GlobalValue@1@PEAVConstant@1@AEBVTwine@1@PEAV01@W4ThreadLocalMode@01@I2@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl createEchoFunction(class CodeGenContext &,class llvm::Function *)" (?createEchoFunction@@YAXAEAVCodeGenContext@@PEAVFunction@llvm@@@Z)    E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   69  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class llvm::Constant * __cdecl llvm::ConstantDataArray::getString(class llvm::LLVMContext &,class llvm::StringRef,bool)" (?getString@ConstantDataArray@llvm@@SAPEAVConstant@2@AEAVLLVMContext@2@VStringRef@2@_N@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl createEchoFunction(class CodeGenContext &,class llvm::Function *)" (?createEchoFunction@@YAXAEAVCodeGenContext@@PEAVFunction@llvm@@@Z)    E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   70  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class llvm::Constant * __cdecl llvm::ConstantExpr::getGetElementPtr(class llvm::Constant *,class llvm::ArrayRef<class llvm::Value *>,bool)" (?getGetElementPtr@ConstantExpr@llvm@@SAPEAVConstant@2@PEAV32@V?$ArrayRef@PEAVValue@llvm@@@2@_N@Z) referenced in function "public: static class llvm::Constant * __cdecl llvm::ConstantExpr::getGetElementPtr(class llvm::Constant *,class llvm::ArrayRef<class llvm::Constant *>,bool)" (?getGetElementPtr@ConstantExpr@llvm@@SAPEAVConstant@2@PEAV32@V?$ArrayRef@PEAVConstant@llvm@@@2@_N@Z)    E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\corefn.obj
Error   71  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl llvm::Module::Module(class llvm::StringRef,class llvm::LLVMContext &)" (??0Module@llvm@@QEAA@VStringRef@1@AEAVLLVMContext@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl CodeGenContext::CodeGenContext(void)" (??0CodeGenContext@@QEAA@XZ)   E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\main.obj
Error   72  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LLVMInitializeX86TargetInfo referenced in function "bool __cdecl llvm::InitializeNativeTarget(void)" (?InitializeNativeTarget@llvm@@YA_NXZ)   E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\main.obj
Error   73  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LLVMInitializeX86Target referenced in function "bool __cdecl llvm::InitializeNativeTarget(void)" (?InitializeNativeTarget@llvm@@YA_NXZ)   E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\main.obj
Error   74  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol LLVMInitializeX86TargetMC referenced in function "bool __cdecl llvm::InitializeNativeTarget(void)" (?InitializeNativeTarget@llvm@@YA_NXZ) E:\Visual Studio\BlueInfrastructureBuild\Infrastructure\main.obj
```

Comment: As I understand VS 2012 is only available in 32 bit flavor. My processor architecture is 64 bit but LLVM `#include "llvm/Target/Targetmachine.h"` and the `InitializeNativeTarget();` always looks into the build platform and return `LLVMInitializeX86TargetMC` for a 32 bit architecture. This requires three `.inc` files:  

    "X86GenRegisterInfo.inc"
     "X86GenInstrInfo.inc"
     "X86GenSubtargetInfo.inc"

I understand they are generated by the system but I am unclear how to generate them.

Comment: The solution here suggests a possible workaround: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710994/clangllvm-static-library-linking-error-on-windows-why-would-the-symbols-be-di)