# LLVM compilation errors on VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, llvm

I have built the LLVM using CMake using VS 2012 in keeping with documentation. I am trying to build a toy compiler with flex, bison and LLVM. The final stage of my compiler my main class looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "codegen.h"
#include "node.h"
#include "llvm/Target/Targetmachine.h"



using namespace std;

extern int yyparse();
extern NBlock* programBlock;

void createCoreFunctions(CodeGenContext& context);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    yyparse();
    std::cout << programBlock << endl;

    InitializeNativeTarget();
    CodeGenContext context;
    createCoreFunctions(context);
    context.generateCode(*programBlock);
    context.runCode();

    return 0;
}
```

As stated in my previous post [LLVM 3.4 linker errors in VS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720578/llvm-3-4-linker-errors-on-vs-2012). To workaround the solution I manually added the x86 files I was missing (taking clue from the errors). I ended up adding the following to the main:

```
#include "llvm-3.4/lib/Target/X86/MCTargetDesc/X86MCTargetDesc.h"
#include "llvm-3.4/lib/Target/X86/InstPrinter/X86ATTInstPrinter.h"
#include "llvm-3.4/lib/Target/X86/InstPrinter/X86IntelInstPrinter.h"
#include "X86MCAsmInfo.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/Triple.h"
#include "llvm/MC/MCCodeGenInfo.h"
#include "llvm/MC/MCInstrAnalysis.h"
#include "llvm/MC/MCInstrInfo.h"
#include "llvm/MC/MCRegisterInfo.h"
#include "llvm/MC/MCStreamer.h"
#include "llvm/MC/MCSubtargetInfo.h"
#include "llvm/MC/MachineLocation.h"
#include "llvm/Support/ErrorHandling.h"
#include "llvm/Support/Host.h"
#include "llvm/Support/TargetRegistry.h"
#include "X86GenRegisterInfo.inc"
#include "X86GenInstrInfo.inc"
#include "X86GenSubtargetInfo.inc"
```

But I noticed that the following are missing from my system:

```
 "X86MCAsmInfo.h"
 "X86GenRegisterInfo.inc"
 "X86GenInstrInfo.inc"
 "X86GenSubtargetInfo.inc"
```

I looked through the online documentation but I am a beginner on the topic, most of it did not make too much sense to me. I would appreciate if someone could guide me or point me to the right tutorial which gives me a better understanding of what I am doing wrong here.